# How to decrease consistency of Postgres database, to speed up updates for table with large number of indices

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, concurrency, query-optimization

I have a Postgres table with a large number of indexed columns (roughly 100 columns total). Any row update causes all indexes to be updated, which is a lot of work for the DB engine.

I *think* based on [this documentation page](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index-locking.html) that reading is not blocked on index updates, but since a row write is atomic, I assume a read that would include a locked row in its result set will cause the read to block. Is this correct?

I also think that the above page is saying that multiple row updates can be underway concurrently, since only a row at a time is locked for index updates, and btree indexes are able to handle concurrent updates. Is this correct? i.e. updates do not block each other unless they are trying to update the same row?

If index updates decrease either read or write throughput, even without row conflicts, then is there a way to tell Postgres that it's OK to update the indexes for a table one at a time, rather than updating all atomically, so that read queries in that table don't get slowed down by the indexes being locked? I'm OK with a lack of consistency in the name of higher concurrency.

Basically I want to understand the read and write concurrency implications of an update operation with this many indexed columns, and with many concurrent readers and writers. I also want to know if there's a way to tune Postgres to trade off consistency for query throughput, for both read and write.

Comment: I think you can find better answers at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: No, not correct, an update of an index doesn't block readers.

Comment: @TheImpaler because my data items have more than 100 attributes! Each attribute needs to be able to be queried, either separately or with other attributes.

Comment: "...Each attribute needs to be able to be queried..." -- The indexing strategy responds to the specific queries you want to optimize. Indexing each and every column of the table *separately* won't necesarily improve query performance. I think you need to focus onthe queries first, then add indexes.

Answer (score -3):

You have two problems... One is probably related to your data model, the other with the limited architecture of PostGreSQL.

**1 - The data model**

A table with 100 indexes requires at least 100 columns, or even many more... In terms of relational databases, the theory of normalization which allows the shaping of relational databases leads to many tables having few columns.
With several dozen columns, you are probably no longer in relational (OLTP) but perhaps in decision-making (OLAP) or in a serious modeling error

**1.1 - Case of OLAP**

In such a case it is necessary to resort to databases specialized in OLAP data storage, this can be the expensive Tarradata or the SSAS part of Microsoft SQL Server.

These engines are able to compress, deduplicate, precalculate and automatically index such data structures, in order to maximize the speed of data acquisition and restitution.

PotsGreSQL is not at all made for this...

**1.2 - Data model**

If your data model does not respect the normal forms which have been developed to reduce IO, then you must correct the structure of your tables by dividing them into smaller tables in terms of number of columns. In this case the update will be much lighter because the number of indexes will be much less!

For my part, practicing database auditing for 30 years, any table with more than 20 columns is suspect in my eyes and when I model databases, I try not to exceed 10 columns (in addition to PK and possible FK).

**2 - Structure of PostGreSQL**

The development of PostGreSQL was built on a model based on processes and not threads... This means that parallelism in PostGreSQL is very limited and expensive... See the differences at:
https://www.guru99.com/difference-between-process-and-thread.html
In particular, PostGreSQL sequentially updates indexes and table rows where other RDBMS do it in parallel...

In other database systems like Microsoft SQL Server act in parallel automatically, allowing shortest read and write response times...

Read the comparative benchmarks I did some time ago on this subject...
[Process maintenance](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-part-1-dba-queries-performances/)
[Count queries](http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/)

The PostGreSQL staff are [considering modifying the engine architecture to move to a threaded model](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/31cc6df9-53fe-3cd9-af5b-ac0d801163f4%40iki.fi), but I fear that we will have to wait many years before this is done...

Another trouble in the PG architecture is the fact, due to MVCC, that every UPDATE is compound a new row as an equivalent of INSERT + DELETE... Which is the worst case...

**IN CONCLUSION**

Aside from the dangerous UNLOGGED mode, three solutions are available to you... Wait for this new version of PostGreSQL based on threads, modify the structure of your tables or change RDBMS!

PS : another solution is to use an "In Memory" database like MS SQL Server does...

Comment: You're making a huge assumption that this table doesn't need all these columns... it does. This is not a modeling error! It is an intrinsic property of the data that I need to store that it has this many columns.

Comment: I would be cautious to recommend SQL Server compared to PostgreSQL. While both have their strengths and limitations, the internal SQL Server engine is not that great and performance deteriorates fast with parallel queries. I have the opposite experience you have in terms of performance and cost. I did not downvote the answer because it provides some good points; however, other ones are not accurate.

Comment: @Luke_Hutchison I will be very curious to see your use case because in my 35 years of database professionnal I have never seen a good reason to choose a RDBMS to process data having more than 100 simultaneous attributes. Remember that RDBMSs are dedicated to data management tasks...

Comment: @The_Impaler Do you have any published benchmarks about the fact that PG will run faster than SQL Server ? I have done and publish many benchmarks that proove the opposite... Like these ones : geospatial https://g-ernaelsten.developpez.com/tutoriels/comparatif-sig-et-performances/, aggregation of intervals https://blog.developpez.com/sqlpro/p9821/langage-sql-norme/agregation_d_intervalles_en_sql_1, dba maintenance http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-part-1-dba-queries-performances/, COUT... http://mssqlserver.fr/postgresql-vs-microsoft-sql-server-comparison-part-2-count-performances/

Comment: @SQLpro It's for a dating app, where users can query against any one of 100 profile attributes. The attributes are all independent, and any one can appear as a query condition, so they all need to be indexed. There is no point splitting them into separate tables, because every single attribute pertains to only one conceptual data object: the user's profile. I do need all 100 indexes, and the data attributes do need to be in separate columns. I guess add this to your 35 years of experience as something new that you have now heard of :-D

Comment: @uke-hutchison This is unfortunately a completely anti-relational design since there is no interdependence of attributes (violation of functional dependencies), and it would be better to use a double entry table with a trigger limiting the number of attributes to 100 per items. In this principle I would have used vertical indexing, as allowed by SQL Server with the "columstore" indexes